# Quadratic terms in regression with categorical variables

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, categorical-data

I am working my way for the first time through predicting a continuous dependent variable in a problem where all independent variables are categorical using python statsmodels. I would like to add to this model 'y ~ + C(x1) + C(x2) + C(x3)' all possible quadratic terms. What is the right notation for that?

EDIT: one of my categorical variables is age, which I binned in four different bins. All other are transformed into dummy. So the idea was to square age.

Comment: Please clarify.  Suppose one of your categorical models is region {East, West, North, or South}.  Would you try to square "East"?

Comment: I imagined that if one of the categories is age, and I build a few age bins, I could still square age and have a meaning associated to it

Answer (score 2):

Quadratic terms for categorical variables are undefined because you cannot square a categorical variable. On the other hand, given that you have a continuous variable with nonlinear relationship to your outcome/dependent variable, categorization may help and be such that it is synonymous to introducing quadratic terms but with the added benefit of simpler model to build and explain.